# Nth Digit From the Right

Tags: scheme, racket

How do you create a function that will allow you to find the Nth digit from the right in a large number? For example, (f 2345 2) will yield 4. I am a beginning student so I am programming with DrRacket and I'm hoping that the code can be usable in Racket.

Comment: Never used racket but you're going to want to use the modulus operator to remove all values to the left of the number you're isolating (something like `2345 % 10^n`). From there you'll want remove the right of the number by dividing by 10^(n-1) and removing the decimal values by casting to an int

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the right most digit is the least significant and thus you can cut it off by taking the quotient by 10 and get the last by taking the remainder by 10.

For nth index you first need to get the remainder of a division by `(expt 10 n)` and the quotient of that and `(expt 10 (- n 1))`.

Imagine your function taking a base such that you can pick the 3rd octal digit like this:

```
(f #o143 #o3 #o10) ; ==> 1
; same in decimal notation
(f 99 3 8)         ; ==> 1
```